# Unable to open keystore in AndroidStudio - "Redundant length bytes found"

Tags: android, macos, java-8, apk, signing

I am unable to open my existing keystore file in Android Studio or use the `jarsigner` from the command line.

In both cases the error message is:

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): Redundant length bytes found

See screenshot:
[image: Android Studio]

Apparently this was an issue that should be fixed with [JDK8_131](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u131-relnotes-3565278.html) but does not work for me. (We are all using OSX)

I also get the same error on travis. (See "Update" section below.)

I found another SO question ([*Signing android app throws IOException: Redundant length bytes found*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554221/signing-android-app-throws-ioexception-redundant-length-bytes-found)) where they converted the `.pkc12` file to `.keystore` but we are already using `.keystore`

---

## UPDATE

I found that the build also started failing on travis because they are moving builds to their new distro `trusty` which downloads the newest JDK whereas `precise` used JDK7 by default. Adding `dist: precise` to the top of the `.travis.yml` file works for now but this is definitely not a permanent solution.

Can we only hope for a JDK update that fixes the issue or is there a way to remove the redundant length bytes from the keystore?

Comment: Not quite sure, but it seems you are hitting this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179191. If it is... it's only fixed in java-9. can you try with java-9 just to see what happens?

Comment: But we are not using openJDK but oracle's JDK

Comment: the code is close to the same in each anyway. and testing against oracle jdk-9 would not hurt

Comment: just to make sure - can you re-produce this with `jdk-9`?

Comment: I have not had time to check yet. But as far as I know JDK9 was not officially released yet, right?

Comment: correct, but it's feature complete anyway - just bug fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to work around this in the end by using to [Google Play App Signing](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#google-play-app-signing).

We used a machine with JDK 7 to follow all the steps as described in the App Signing tutorial.

We then created the new keystore with a JDK9 machine.

Comment: what steps did you do exactly? i have the same issue. thanks

Comment: I have yet to take this step because the process is irreversible once initiated however I may be going this direction very soon.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error and I fixed it by following Solution 1 below. you can try Solution 1 to resolve it. Else follow the other Solutions.

## Solution 1

> Updating JDK from 7 to 8

## Solution 2

You can run the following command to list the content of your keystore file:

```
keytool -list -keystore .keystore
```

If you are looking for a specific alias, you can also specify it in the command:

```
keytool -list -keystore .keystore -alias foo
```

If the alias is not found, it will display an exception:

```
 keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias does not exist
```

## Solution 3

In order to get all the details I had to add the `-v` option

```
keytool -v -list -keystore <FileName>.keystore
```

It will surely help you to solve the error or you can get the contents of your keystore and can generate a new keystore of your app.

Comment: sugansoft i agree your answer... great i was looking for long. but simply its fixed and saved my time ....

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. First of all the issue occured when we updated to JDK8. Second `keytool` is the tool that gets invoked by Android Studio. So when using `keytool` I get exactly the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue and none of the solutions worked.

I finally got it working by upgrading to Google's new app signing by uploading the private key generated with pepk tool and asked their support to reset the upload key.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue too, but your solution does not work for me : pepk tool produces exactly same error "Redundant length bytes found". Did you do something to get pepk work?